# Как растянуть img на весь экран монитора?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="bgc">
 <img src="img.jpg" width="1920" height="1000">
</div>
```

чтобы при масштабировании до любых размеров она всегда занимала 100% монитора, а не при достижении ширины монитора свыше 1920px снизу начинало бы появляться пустое место. Уточняю - картинка находится на html-странице и не нужно ее запускать через css - backgroun-image

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/989w5yd0/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как обычно : пользуемся не инлайновыми стилями а в **отдельном файле**

```css
html,body{
height:100%;
}

img{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="">
```

но так же надо помнить что изображение должно быть в **альбомном виде**

Comment: http://master.transkribator.ru/lazga.png я об этом и говорю

Comment: для html,body стили задали ? я лишь вижу у вас инлайновые стили width="1920" height="1000"

Comment: конечно, я уже это кручу вторые сутки

Comment: вам сверху дали явный пример -

Comment: опять не то - при задании 100vh - это вся высота браузера, а нижних 40px и верхних 40px съедает и это тоже никак не поправить, так как любые обертки браузер в этом случае не учитывает

Comment: https://codepen.io/MaximLensky/pen/LOYeYX  вот смотри

Comment: http://master.transkribator.ru/lazga.png этот код в реальном браузере

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67819/discussion-between---and-proshka).

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо, если изображение абстрактное и деформация при непропорциональном масштабировании не заметна... Можно, с помощью jQuery скрыть изображение, забрать его `src` и подложить его в ненавистный вам `background-image`, и добавить `background-size: cover`...

Можно попробовать использовать `object-fit` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/1000/sports/Dummy-Text/" />
```

Comment: нет он не ненавистный, просто экспериментировал с картинками в html и не смог добиться нужного результата. Однако - спасибо

Comment: немного поправил код. вот теперь "на здоровье" =)